# Insert all the SQLite rows to array swift

Tags: swift, sqlite

I make a global array var

```
var select: [String] = []
```

and select data from my sqlite in override func viewDidLoad().

```
if sqlite3_prepare(db, sel, -1, &sell, nil) == SQLITE_OK {
        print("prepare sel aman")
        
        while (sqlite3_step(sell) == SQLITE_ROW){
            let id = sqlite3_column_int(sell, 0)
            guard let nam = sqlite3_column_text(sell, 1) else {return}
            guard let tang = sqlite3_column_text(sell, 2) else {return}
            
            let ma = String(cString: nam)
            let gal = String(cString: tang)
            
            let data = ("\(id). \(ma), \(gal)")
            var arraydata = [data]
            select = arraydata.append
            print (select)
        }
        
    }
```

when i run, the program only show the last data i insert in my tableview

```
["3. njay, 2021-08-04 03:47:47"]
```

this is the program output = [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgJIB.png)

total data i insert is 3

```
["1. maul, 2021-08-04 03:37:16"]
["2. haw-haw, 2021-08-04 03:37:25"]
["3. njay, 2021-08-04 03:47:47"]
```

how can i insert all of my rows to the global array and show the all data to my tableview?

Comment: Are you hitting print (select) every time?

Comment: That code doesn't look like it should compile. The `select = arraydata.append` shouldn't work. But, the issue is that you're not appending to the end of the array. It should be `select.append(data)`

Comment: What's this?  It doesn't make sense.  select = arraydata.append

Comment: thanks guys, i'm still new and no experient at programing especially on Swift. that's why my program so messy hahaha